How can I refresh an access token for an Azure app that uses the WAM broker
I have an Azure app that returns a bearer access token. I use the Windows Account Manager (WAM) so there's a special redirect URI. I'm using the following code to refresh the token but I'm getting a 400 response. I am sending the access code before it expires and I get the redirect URI right off Azure. I'm not certain though on the url of the PostAsync:
public async Task<string> RefreshTokenAsync(string refreshToken, string Tenant, string Instance, string ClientId)
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ClientId),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", refreshToken),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "ms-appx-web://microsoft.aad.brokerplugin/" + ClientId)

                });

                var response = await client.PostAsync($"{Instance}{Tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token", content);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponse>(responseJson);
                    return responseObject.AccessToken;
                }
                else
                {
                    string a = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    MessageBox.Show(a , "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }

        }

        public class TokenResponse
        {
            [JsonProperty("access_token")]
            public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        }

Is there a simpler way to refresh a token?

AFAIK WAM and MSAL stores the refresh token in the cache check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-wam#token-cache-persistence and it is used and updated t's used and updated silently if needed when calling AcquireTokenSilent check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/how-to/token-cache-serialization?tabs=desktop#token-cache-types

The Web Account Manager (WAM) API, provided by Windows, handles the refresh of the access token automatically when it is expired. When you call the GetTokenSilentlyAsync method and the access token is expired, WAM will automatically attempt to refresh the token using the refresh token stored in the token cache.

Thanks. I am using WAM and I do get the token silently when it's available. And, from what you suggested, Windows will automatically update the token if I call GetTokenSilentlyAsync. Should I call this function each time before I use the token to make sure it's refreshed? There's also a refresh token somewhere. Where's that stored and can I use that to refresh the token?

Yes the refresh token will be stored in the cache

You can call GetTokenSilentlyAsync function refer the link

Did the above suggestion work?

I can refresh the token, as you suggested with GetTokenSilentlyAsyn(). Seems to work fine. I would like to get the code I posted above to work. However, I admit with a bit of shame, I can't find where the RefreshToken can be found to pass it to the function. The AuthenticationResult that is returned after authentication only has the access token and that isn't the same and doesn't work. I use a token cache (a generic one from the Microsoft library) but I don't know how to find it in there either. I can refresh the token silently but I sure would like to find that RefreshToken

Are you not able to see the refresh token in token cache?

Other than the AuthenticationResult, I don't know how to access tokens. I have the TokenCacheHelper that I mentioned, it stores a file to disk. But I don't otherwise know how to access the token cache. Is it a part of IPublicClientApplication?

In TokenCacheHeloer can you see the tokens?

I don't really have access to the token cache helper. It's assigned when I create the IPublicClientApplication.       MsalCacheHelper cacheHelper = CreateCacheHelperAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
cacheHelper.RegisterCache(_clientApp.UserTokenCache);

Based on the document GetTokenSilentlyAsync is required to refresh the access tokensilently
